# Incorrect popup shadow position after moving popup in RichFaces 4.x

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I have popup with autosized attribute. Panel contains fields for search, search button, datatable and datascroller. After press search button or select page in datascroller javascript is called. Javascript is used for move popup to center of browser visible area. All work fine, except popup shadow is stay for previous panel position when popup is already moved.

Button code:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="searchButton"
    value="#{msg.search}"
    action="#{chAction.searchSegments}"
    styleClass="richButton"
    render="clientCategoryCandidateTable"
    oncomplete="centerPanel();" />
```

Javascript:

```
function centerPanel() {
    var modalPanel = #{rich:component('addToSegmentsPanel')};
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupWidth = modalPanel.width();
    var popupHeight = modalPanel.height();
    modalPanel.setLeft(Math.max(0, (windowWidth-popupWidth)/2));
    modalPanel.setTop(Math.max(0, (windowHeight-popupHeight)/2));
};
```

I have tried different version of javascript, but with same side effect:

```
function centerPopup() {
    var popup = #{rich:component('addToSegmentsPanel')};
    popup.moveTo(Math.max(0, (window.innerWidth-popup.width())/2),
                 Math.max(0, (window.innerHeight-popup.height())/2));
};
```

Screen shots:
[image: Popup before call javascript]
[image: Popup after call javascript]

Thanks for any help or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was fixed with adding hide and show in end of javascript:

```
modalPanel.hide(); modalPanel.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem on calling resize () action of the popup. 
In your case, it should be `modalPanel.resize()`.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. Your approach works fine with shadow, but it don't allow change popup width. As result data in datatable displayed not in 1 line (expected result) but in multi lines (name, type, description). My version resize not only window, but and datatable in proper size.

Comment: I tried with multi-row in datatable. It resizes properly. In datatable, I put no styling in column.

Comment: I have opposite situation: popup contains datatable with pagination, datatable doesn't have strict column width, on 1st page I have rows with short name, on 2nd page some rows have long name. After next page click the `centerPanel` javascript is called and popup is re-centered. Until this your code works. But I want to display all data in 1 line (resize datatable if it needed). This part is not covered with your code. Data is displayed as multiline. Maybe it can be fixed with adding column width or no wrap style for data. Problem was solved 5 months ago. Thanks for your solution.