# Rich popupPanel does not resize automatically

Tags: richfaces, autosize, popuppanel

I got a rich:popupPanel like the following:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="someId" header="some header" domElementAttachment="parent" autosized="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="searchGrid">
        <h:outputText value="some value:" />
        <h:inputText id="someOtherId" value="#{someModel.value}" required="true" maxlength="12" size="14"/>
        <rich:message for="someOtherId" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <br />

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="someButtons">
        <a4j:commandButton id="someButton" value="search" action="#{someCtrl.doSomething()}" render="@this" execute="someId"
            oncomplete="if (#{empty facesContext.messageList}) {#{rich:component('someId')}.hide();}" />
        <a4j:commandButton value="cancel" render="tabs" execute="@this" oncomplete="#{rich:component('someId')}.hide(); return false;" />
        <rich:message for="someButton" />
    </h:panelGrid>

</rich:popupPanel>
```

It seems like this problem has been solved [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13710), but it still doesn't work for me. I got the following dependency to richfaces:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final-redhat-1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Maybe the problem is that I use this supported version from JBOSS? Or does someone know how I can achieve a resize dependent of the content of the panel?

Comment: Change link to JIRA. Please explain "doesn't work for me".

Comment: Thx for the hint. Still doesn't work for me means, that I still get a scrollbar in my popupPanel...My current workaround is to test if the facesContext.messageList is empty and if so, I do a #{rich:component('someId')}.show(); My panel get's rewritten and accordingly ressized...

Comment: Posted answer doesn't contain `#{rich:component('someId')}.show()` code. That code should be part of javascript or `onclick` action of `commandButton`/`commandLink`/`graphicImage`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570194/incorrect-popup-shadow-position-after-moving-popup-in-richfaces-4-x), it may help you.

Comment: As I mentioned, your suggestion is my actual workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rich Faces defect https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13655
I don't know was it applied for 4.3.7.Final or not because the issue has no hash of commit. 
The repository https://github.com/richfaces4/components